# How to fix gap on HTML table with rounded corners?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have no access to change core HTML, only CSS, but the tables I am working with have a weird gap in the corners that I am trying to fix.

```css
.tabular-container {
  border: 2px solid #0093c9;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.heading-row {
  background: #0093c9;
  font-weight: bold;
}

table {
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabular-container">
  <table class="">
    <thead class="">
      <tr class="heading-row">
        <th colspan="2">Rounded corners table</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="tabular__row">
        <td>kk</td>
        <td>kk</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tabular__row">
        <td colspan="2">This is a sample table only</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add background color to the thead?

Comment: What sort of gap? Any chance of even a partial screen-shot?

Comment: @MikeBrockington If you see in the snippet, in the top left and right corners of table there's a gap.

Comment: @FunkDoc yes I can add a bg color - just tried this, and works better than current is :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does turning the whole table and div background into the color and the tbody back to white do the trick?

```
.tabular-container {
  background: #0093c9;
}

table {
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #0093c9;
}

tbody{
  background: white;
}
```

```css
.tabular-container {
  border: 2px solid #0093c9;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #0093c9;
}

.heading-row th{
  font-weight: bold;
}

table {
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #0093c9;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

tbody{
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabular-container">
  <table class="">
    <thead class="">
      <tr class="heading-row">
        <th colspan="2">Rounded corners table</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="tabular__row">
        <td>kk</td>
        <td>kk</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tabular__row">
        <td colspan="2">This is a sample table only</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me to solve the issue, I think it's because all possible backgrounds are the blue color, i.e. the containing div, table itself, the table heading, it leaves no chance of any other color showing through even if there's any gaps at all. Simple solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple, set: `border-radius:0;` on your table.

The browser is trying to set the radius of the table's corners to match, but is getting a rounding error. By using radius:0 you are forcing the browser to 'clip' the corner instead.

Comment: thanks, it made a slight improvement but for me still has the gap.